# Android Room wait until insertion is finished

Tags: android, android-room

I have a screen which adds an entry to a table and then redirect the user back to the main screen. In the main screen, the app show the user all the entries in the table.

I worked as described [here](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view#12) and he mention that insertions can't be made from the main thread. Hence, we use thread pool.

Now, I trigger an insertion in another thread using the thread pool and redirect the user to the main screen. Hence, it is possible that he won't see the data that he inserted.

What I want to achieve is that he would wait in the "add new data" fragment and be redirected only after the insertion is finished. I would disable the components in the screen and show a "saving" message.

What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Just don't trigger navigation directly in the UI thread. Then you get it. Here is an example:

```java
// In your insert Runnable
public void run() {
    // Your database insertion code etc.
    . . .
    new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(() -> {
        // Here, trigger your fragment back transaction e.g. popBackStack()
    });
}
```

Since I don't see your code I can only help so far.